# Magento 2 category and attributes cleared after adding a configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-relations

I'm trying to add a configurable product, but after generating configurations and saving the the product I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '402-2154' for key 'CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID_PARENT_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_super_link` (`product_id`,`parent_id`) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)
```

Despite of the error, the Configurable product is saved. The main problem is, that sometimes, not always, all relationships for all products are cleared, so when I add configurable product I loose all categories, custom attributes relationships and so on.

Did anyone encounter this problem? How can it be related to the Duplicate entry error?